# How to find similarity between 2 dependency trees using spaCy?

Tags: python, tree, nlp, spacy

I am working on a question-answering task. I am planning to use dependency parsing to find candidate answers from a passage to a query. However, I am not sure how I can find similarity between dependency trees of the query and the sentences from the passage, respectively. Below is the reproducible code.

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

doc1 = nlp('Wall Street Journal just published an interesting piece on crypto currencies')
doc2 = nlp('What did Wall Street Journal published')

displacy.render(doc1, style='dep', jupyter=True, options={'distance': 90})
displacy.render(doc2, style='dep', jupyter=True, options={'distance': 90})
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem you are having? All you are currently doing is displaying the trees, there is no attempt at solving this.

Comment: @Lomtrur I want to find similarity between a pair of dependency trees.

Comment: And what have you tried to solve it? It looks like you have tried exactly nothing (other than displaying the parse trees) and now expect someone to solve the entire problem for you.

Comment: @Lomtrur I want to solve a question-answering task with the help of dependency parsing. I am asking you to solve the entire problem. Just want to find a way to match 2 dependency trees.

Answer (score 0):

This might be want you looking for:

https://github.com/tomkwiat/dependency-graph-similarity-measure

It's on Java, but should be easy to port to Python.

Another thing you might investigate are papers on kernel graph similarities.

Comment: Thanks a lot @David

Comment: glad to help, I knew a few years ago finding some nice papers about what you exactly want to do, but I can't recall the title, nor finding them, but give it a try, it's a well-researched topic, tree-graph similarity

Comment: Sure I will try it out.